# Is there any builder site for bicycle?

Tags: parts, compatibility, upgrades, build

Say you want to build entirely your own bike, from frame to ring bell. Is there a site that can help you with compatibility among all parts? Or maybe you just want to upgrade your crank set but you don't know what else you must upgrade (BB? Pedals? Front derailleur?)

I'm thinking something like PC Part Picker or Logical Increments for pc's.

Comment: The [Park Tool](https://www.parktool.com/) site has a lot of useful information.  And [Sheldon Brown's](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/) site has a lot of good info as well.

Comment: Shimano provides extensive specification and compatibility info for their products https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/

Comment: The answer below is correct. However, here's some nice reading on selecting the parts for a custom build. It does outline what you need to look for in terms of compatibility. https://cyclingtips.com/2018/05/how-to-handle-a-custom-bike-build-2/

Comment: There was a company in Massachusetts (Hottubes) that would teach you to construct your own frame. It was like a middle age fantasy vacation. You spent a week in their shop learning to weld your own frame and assemble the bike. It was not  inexpensive but could be a once in a life experience.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a site that can help you with compatibility among all parts?

Yes

There are sites that will let you pick all of the compatible components for a bicycle.

The following are sites built by people who want to make money selling you a custom bike (these are examples of bike builder apps, not recommendations).

[Fanatic.com has a bike builder feature on their website](https://www.fanatikbike.com/products/bike-builder) for mountain bikes for a specific set of brands.

[Wrenchscience.com also has a bike builder](https://www.wrenchscience.com/) on their website for a variety of bike types and brands.

You can build a bike on these sites and then use the list of parts to purchase from whomever you like.

For an example of a bike builder that does not appear to be tied to a store.
[Bike Config is a 3D app](http://www.bikeconfig.com/) that custom builds a bicycle. It appears to be all mountain bikes with a limited list of parts but they hope to grow.

Searching "build a bicycle online" will deliver these and other options.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks to you I found https://cyclingbuilder.com/ that is for bikes what  https://pcpartpicker.com/ is for Pc's.

Comment: Unfortunately, cyclingbuilder.com is shut down. But if you're still looking for a site to find compatible parts, check out https://builder.bike. It's my own personal project @EliseoOcampos

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of my favorites. Lots of builders, shop owners, mechanics and bike nerds frequent the forum.  Truly a wealth of information:
[Velocipede Salon Forum](https://www.velocipedesalon.com/forum/)

Comment: It's a good forum, and you could definitely get sound advice there. However, it's not the sort of automated site that the OP was talking about.